# How to delay callout from showing when annotation selected in MKMapView? Swift 4

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview, callouts

(This is my first stack overflow question haha)

UPDATE:
From this link - [Center MKMapView BEFORE displaying callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397934/center-mkmapview-before-displaying-callout)

I implemented the solution from Thermometer, however selecting and deselecting the annotation makes it look like my application is glitching.

I think the best way would be to delay the callOut (detail pop up) from appearing by a few seconds so the map has time to move first.

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let annotation = view.annotation else {
        return
    }

    let currentAnnotation = view.annotation as? MapMarker
    Global.currentAnnotation = currentAnnotation
    findRelatinoshipLines()

    if Global.showLifeStoryLines {
        var locations = lifeStoryAnnotations.map { $0.coordinate }
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &locations, count: locations.count)
        Global.finalLineColor = Global.lifeStoryColor
        mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
    }

    if Global.showFatherLines {
        var fatherLocations = fatherTreeAnnotations.map { $0.coordinate }
        let fatherPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &fatherLocations, count: fatherLocations.count)
        Global.finalLineColor = Global.fatherLineageColor

        mapView.addOverlay(fatherPolyline)
    }

    if Global.showMotherLines {
        var motherLocations = motherTreeAnnotations.map { $0.coordinate }
        let motherPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &motherLocations, count: motherLocations.count)
        Global.finalLineColor = Global.motherLineageColor

        mapView.addOverlay(motherPolyline)
    }

    if Global.showSpouseLines {
        var locations = spouseAnnotations.map { $0.coordinate }
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &locations, count: locations.count)
        Global.finalLineColor = Global.spouseColor
        mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
    }

    if Global.zoomChange == true {
        Global.zoomChange = false
    } else {
        let currentRegion = mapView.region
        let span = currentRegion.span
        let location = currentAnnotation!.coordinate
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            mapView.setCenter(annotation.coordinate, animated: true)
            //mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

CONTINUED:

Basically I'm working on a family genealogy application that displays events from relatives on a map.

When I click an annotation (event) the details (who event belongs to, where and when, etc) pops up above with an information button to show the selected person.

I have it set up to set the `MKMapView` region so that the selected annotation is centered each time a new annotation is clicked.

The problem is when I click an event that is on the edge of the screen, my annotation title/description pops up off centered so that it fits on my screen because it doesn't know that I plan on re-centering the map view around said annotation.

I was wondering if there was any way to make the title/description appear centered directly above the selected annotation so that when I move the map everything is centered and fits on the screen.

Here are some screenshots of what I'm talking about:

[Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqDAPm.png)

Comment: Will help if you show the code that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: You should center the map before details pops up.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Yes I'm looking into doing that now with the help of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397934/center-mkmapview-before-displaying-callout

Comment: @KosukeOgawa I implemented the solution from Thermometer on that link, however selecting and deselecting the annotation makes it look like my application is glitching. Do you have any other way of delaying the showCallout (details pop up)?

Comment: @MwcsMac updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by calling `setCenter` with a slight delay in `mapView(_:didSelect:)`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let annotation = view.annotation else {
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        mapView.setCenter(annotation.coordinate, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and instead of delaying the pop up - it delays the map centering. Check my post update for my code.

Comment: Is this because my annotations are markers and not pins?